# file_get_contents request to Instagram API timing out

Tags: php, instagram, file-get-contents, instagram-api, connection-timeout

I have been using the same method for almost two years to pull in my instagram feed onto my homepage.  Suddenly, today my whole site is crashing based on a connection timeout when using:

```
file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=' . $token . '&count=8');
```

I see that Instagram has recently updated their API, but I cannot get a response from them on the matter.  When I enter the url in my browser I receive my json immediately.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution. I have been working on it longer than I would have liked. I hope it will help you.

```
function insta_rulz($url) {
    try {
    $curl_connection = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $data = json_decode(curl_exec($curl_connection), true);
    curl_close($curl_connection);
        return $data;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}

$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{USERID}/media/recent/?access_token={ACCES_TOKEN}";
$results_array = insta_rulz($url);


$limit = 12; // provide the limit
$image_array= array(); // array to store images.
$userRed_array = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
        $latest_array = $results_array['data'][$i];
        if($latest_array['images'] > 0) {
            $image_array[$i] = $latest_array['images']['standard_resolution'];
        }
    }

    foreach($image_array as $obj){
         array_push($arrList, $obj);
    }
echo json_encode($arrList);
```

Comment: Even though the question is about *experience*, I think your answer should have been mentioned in comments, since it is not very insightful...

Answer (score -1):

Example of working Instagram PHP API:

```
<?php
$api['url'] = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USERID?access_token=XXXX';
$api['urlcontents'] = file_get_contents($api['url']);
$api['response'] = json_decode($api['urlcontents']);
echo $api['response']->data->bio;
?>
```

The API **without JSON decode** must return like:

`{
"data": {
    "id": "1574083",
    "username": "snoopdogg",
    "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
    "bio": "This is my bio",
    "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",`

Comment: my file_get_contents is returning properly formatted json when I enter it in the browser.  But giving me a connection timeout when implemented in my code.